# Content container not aligning under header

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to make the content container on [this page](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html) sit below the header without adding 3ems of padding to the top.

Here's the main CSS:

```
.headerHighlight {
position: absolute;
top: 133px;
}

.header {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 133px;
}

#main-content {
padding: 3em 15px 2em;
overflow: hidden;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. remove `body padding-top`. 
 2. add `margin-top:133px` to `#main-content` and remove his `padding-top`. 
3. you're welcome :)
 **OR**
 you can set the `padding-top` for the body, equal to the fixed height of the header, and remove `padding-top` and `margin-top` for the main-content

Comment: thanks for the objective advice. Maybe next time you can also give some on-topic advices too ;)

Comment: I missed the body padding, needed another pair of eyes - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove top padding from body and leave only height for `.header` class:

```
body {
    background: #E9ECEF url("/images/dark_bg.jpg") repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 960px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.7;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #E9ECEF url("/images/dark_bg.jpg") repeat;
    height: 133px;
}
```